# How to render FORTRAN overprinting in HTML?

Tags: display, simulator, fortran

Consider a FORTRAN program

```
    РRINТ 1
 1  FОRМАТ(1Х,’ GООD ВУЕ НЕLLО, WОRLD’/’+ХХХХ ХХХ’)
    ЕND
```

(YMMV re the number of leading spaces to align Xes with "GOOD BYE")

Its output, using the SIMH convention of denoting overprinting with the carriage return character, is

```
   GООD ВУЕ НЕLLО, WОRLD^M  ХХХХ ХХХ
```

My question is, how to convert it efficiently and reliably to HTML to display as intended?

Searching for "HTML overprint" yields irrelevant results or examples of very fancy overprinting using individual CSS specifications for each letter; obviously not what I want. Adding "fortran" yields descriptions of how to achieve overprinting in FORTRAN, not how to render the result in HTML.

Comment: I'm not sure whether any question containing "HTML" would qualify as a valid question for this site.

Comment: This is clearly a question about HTML and can be shortened to simply "how to overprint in HTML".  The asker's goal of displaying Fortran output is incidental.  That said, individual CSS may be the only option here.  I don't think this type of overprinting was ever anticipated in HTML.

Comment: Your FORTRAN source appears to be mostly UTF-8 characters; for example the O in `FORMAT` is really `О`, U+041E, Cyrillic Capital Letter O.

Comment: You'd probably get a more useful response on SO than here.

Comment: @scruss The reason is that the internal character set of the emulator I've used is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOST_10859

Comment: @Ken You're right, and I've implied HTML/CSS. The reason to ask here is that the rationale is specific to retrocomputing: I want to be able to render FORTRAN printouts in an online emulator.

Comment: This might be off-topic; it's useful for publishing FORTRAN code ouput but is most definitely asking about the use of a non-retro markup language for non-retro software running on non-retro machines. I'll review this after some sleep.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Food for thought: would a question about a way to reproduce the bit-manipulated PWM sound of a retro-computer, or a way to reproduce the CRT artifacts of a videoterminal of a mainframe on non-retro machines (PCs, Macs) in non-retro emulators using a non-retro library (say, SDL) be off-topic?

Comment: @LeoB. Questions on the waveform, static etc. (the characteristics themselves) would be on-topic, but questions on how to go about *implementing* those would be off-topic... I think. As the famous proverb goes; "If in doubt, ask on Meta".

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I see. Would you like me to close or delete this question? One bit of on-topic information I've gathered from it, though, is that there is a problem with my FORTRAN system or the emulator: according to the  FORTRAN carriage-control document, there should not be a space before "GOOD" for the proper alignment.

Comment: @LeoB. This question should not be deleted. As for closure, let's let the community decide.

Comment: This is really a somewhat tricky HTML question (there are ways to position things atop other things, but I can't seem to get reliable positioning), so I'd really suggest asking on Stackoverflow in a more generic form ("How to overlap lines of code in HTML").

Comment: @LeoB. Pingback: [Are questions about modern re-implementations on-topic?](//meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/370/278)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Experimenting with CSS along the lines (pun intended) of "line-height:0"
yielded [this satisfactory result](http://jsbin.com/moxulonufo/edit?html,css,output)

```
.over { line-height: 0; margin-top: 0.5em; margin-bottom: -0.5em; }

<pre>FIRST LINE
PREVIOUS LINE
<div class="over">GOOD BYE
XXXX XXX HELLO WORLD</div>
NEXT LINE
LAST LINE</pre>
```

Things are slightly trickier: the default line height is "roughly" 1.2em, so 0.6 and -0.6, or 50% and -50% of the current line height, will be likely better; however, line height may vary depending on the browser and the font, so the universal solution is still elusive.

Comment: The effect can be enhanced by using a semi-transparent color for the text (e.g. `rgba(0,63,0,0.4)`) so that overprinting the same text multiple times will make it appear darker than showing it once.

Answer (score 3):

[FORTRAN carriage-control](https://www.ibiblio.org/pub/languages/fortran/ch2-14.html) from record-based IO on legacy systems can be quite challenging on modern octet-stream systems. If SIMH is using CRs and BSs to format output, the traditional way of cleaning up the stream is to use [col -b](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/col.1.html) as a filter to merge the control characters.

**Update**: Okay, so this *is* a question about HTML overprinting, for which there seems to be no acceptable cross-platform solution, and any answer to that would be well out of scope for RCSE. Here's an SVG-based possible solution:

[image]

(fail-safe image: [image: overstrike])

This was made with:

```
echo -e 'GOOD BYE HELLO WORLD\rXXXX XXX' | enscript -B -o hello.ps
ps2eps --ignoreBB -l hello.ps
epstopdf hello.eps
pdf2svg hello.pdf hello.svg
```

Comment: I don't want to "clean up" the stream. I want to render it as intended. [enscript](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/enscript1.html) is able to do it in PostScript, but its HTML output is as bad as `col -b`.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding what you want: I'm suggesting `col -b` as a precursor to enclosing the output in `<pre> ... </pre>` for HTML. Did you want the overwritten characters to be kept somehow?  There's no support for overprinting in HTML, so you may have to filter through enscript, render the output as an image, and include that.

Comment: -- Did you want the overwritten characters to be kept somehow? -- Of course, that's the point. -- There's no support for overprinting in HTML -- Naturally, not in the bare HTML, but there should be a way to do that in HTML/CSS. An "obvious" solution proposed on SO [results in wrong line spacing](http://jsbin.com/suxukeximo/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way:`<div>` is a block level element, so you're always likely to get padding and margins inherited and have to apply various browser-specific fixes. This is not really what HTML is for. I'll update my answer with an SVG route that at least will render on most modern browsers.

Comment: I would think that there should be a way to define two new tags in CSS (a custom "pre" and a custom "div") with the appropriate control of line padding and margins. Unfortunately, on SO if a question isn't answered to the author's  satisfaction in the first few minutes, it gets buried and the chance to get the correct answer becomes slim.

Comment: Thank you; it appears that using SVG is the most straightforward way.

Comment: Not sure if my proposed solution handles ГОСТ–10859 very well, though you might be able to do something with recode/iconv to keep the character representations accurate. enscript seems to be the only converter I can find that handles overprinting, and it supports ISO 8859-5.